# How to use XLABS FrameWork

Tags: xamarin, xlabs, xamarin.forms.labs

Currently I am learning Xamarin. While searching MVVM Pattern, I found XLABS Framework.

I have tried downloaded XLABS (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) and try to execute it but its generate error. "System" not found. "Xamarin.Forms" not found. blah blah blah.......

I have tried to resolved it and finally execute it in Android Simulator, but its crash while launching.

Please anyone guide me how to use XLABS (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) Framework using Visual Studio 2017.

Its would be great if anyone suggest, any help document or readymade sample using XLABS to download.

Thanks in advance for time.

Waiting for reply

Regards

Kapil Dave

Answer (score 0):

XLabs is no longer maintained and they state it may no longer work with newer versions of Xamarin Forms.

I would recommend using FreshMvvm as an MVVM framework.

It was specifically designed to work with Xamarin Forms and I have successfully used it on 3 recent projects.

[Here is a starter guide](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm)

Comment: Hi Steve Chadbourne, Thanks for your quick reply,

But as per GIT Version, https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs, someone has push new changes before 10 Months. Still XLabs is no longer maintained.